# Unable to install Rattle on maOS Mojave running R 3.6.1

Tags: macos, mac, r

Followed all the 4 install options as prescribed in the mentioned link:
https://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-mac.html

Every time I try to open Rattle:

- in Rstudio, it restarts with a message "R encountered a fatal error'
- in R console, it hangs after giving message -  *** caught segfault *** adress 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Comment: You should contact the developer of the software.

Comment: already posted on the rattle user groups on Google group. Awaiting response. Reached out here as per the instruction from the group admin